# How to compare rows and columns in two different big excel files correctly in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Good day. There are several excel files of large size (280,000+ lines). In each of them there is a column with unique IDs and a column with a value corresponding to each ID. It is necessary for the ID of the first file to compare the value corresponding to the ID with the value in the second file, if they are not equal, then with the value in the third file, etc. to the fifth file. If no equal value is found, then it is necessary to write the ID and its value to the new excel file.
Example:

```
(first excel file)  (second excel file)
ID  Value              ID    Value
1    100               2      200
2    200               3      888
3    300               1      100
```

It is necessary for the program to compare the value for each ID and write the non-matching ID and its value in the third file (in this case, 3 and 888 or 3 and 300)

I wrote a python program using openpyxl, but when I try to write a set of values ​​to the dictionary, the program hangs and the computer’s memory is running low.

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.getcwd()

def xls_to_dict(filename, max_row):
    print('Opening file' + filename)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    data_dict = {}
    for row in range(2, max_row + 1):
        data_dict[sheet['B' + str(row)].value] = sheet['X' + str(row)].value
    return data_dict

def dict_to_xls(data_dict):
    wb = workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    for next_row in range(1, len(data_dict) + 1):
        policy_id, current = data_dict.popitem()
        sheet.cell(column = 1, row = next_row, value = policy_id)
        sheet.cell(column = 2, row = next_row, value = current)
    return wb

insis_dict = xls_to_dict('ALF_T_REP_PROFIT.xlsx', 253840)
qlik_20_dict = xls_to_dict('Qlik - 20.05.2019', 230725)
qlik_21_dict = xls_to_dict('Qlik - 21.05.2019', 230725)
qlik_22_dict = xls_to_dict('Qlik - 22.05.2019', 230725)
qlik_23_dict = xls_to_dict('Qlik - 23.05.2019', 230725)

empty_polices = {}
diff_polices = {}
for key in insis_dict:
    if key not in qlik_20_dict:
        diff_polices[key] = insis_data[key]
        continue
    if insis_dict[key] == qlik_20_dict[key]:
        continue
    elif insis_dict[key] == qlik_21_dict[key]:
        continue
    elif insis_dict[key] == qlik_22_dict[key]:
        continue
    elif insis_dict[key] == qlik_23_dict[key]:
        continue
    else:
        empty_polices[key] = insis_data[key]

dict_to_xls(empty_polices).save('empty_polices.xlsx')
dict_to_xls(diff_polices).save('diff_polices.xlsx')
```

Is there any other way to compare the values ​​of each ID in different excel files and record discrepancies in a new excel file? Maybe someone knows how to do this with built-in excel tools?

Comment: Are all `Id`'s present in all files?

Comment: With whatever implementation you go with, if you are truly having problems with memory limitations, convert everything to an `int` before you stuff it into a dictionary/set/list.  Much more compact than working with `strings`.

Comment: Are you only interested `ID,value`'s in `file1` that are not in `file2`,`file3`,`file4`...? Or if there  is a `ID,value` *match* between `file2` and `file3` then that pair does not get written to the new file?

Comment: To be honest, I'd convert the relevant worksheets to Pandas dataframes and use the builtin tools for the comparison. Much easier than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

Setup: csv *files* instead of excel files.

```
import io, csv
s = '''ID,Value
1,100
2,200
3,300
4,400''' 
base = io.StringIO(s)

s = '''ID,Value
2,200
3,888
1,100
4,222'''
f2 = io.StringIO(s)

s = '''ID,Value
4,333
2,200
3,888
1,100'''
f3 = io.StringIO(s)
```

---

Read through the base file and create a dictionary

```
d = {}
reader = csv.reader(base)
next(reader)
for k,v in reader:
    d[k] = v
```

Read through the other files; if a *match* is found put the `Id` in a set

```
found = set()

for f in [f2,f3]:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for k,v in reader:
        if d[k] == v:
            found.add(k)
```

Using `Id`'s that were NOT found, create a new file using the `Value`'s from the base dictionary.

```
missing = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(missing)
writer.writerow(['Id','Value'])
for key in found.symmetric_difference(d):
    writer.writerow([key,d[key]])
```

---

This may be better. Read through the base file and put `(ID,value)` tuples in a set. Read through the other files; if a *match* is found remove that tuple from the set. Write all remaining tuples in the set to a new file.

```
reader = csv.reader(base)
next(reader)
base_values = set() 
for ID,value in reader:
    base_values.add((ID,value))

for f in [f2,f3]:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        thing = tuple(row)
        if thing in base_values:
            base_values.remove(thing)

missing2 = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(missing2)
writer.writerow(['Id','Value'])
writer.writerows(base_values)
```

Comment: The first file contains more IDs than the other four files. The IDs in the other four files are the same, only the value is different.

Comment: @Jeff H 
I cannot convert to int, because the ID contains not only numbers, but also letters